# array output disappearing

Tags: excel, vba

```
o = UBound(vSrc, 1)
    ReDim vpf(UBound(vSrc, 1))

For t = 1 To UBound(vSrc, 1)

vpf(t) = WorksheetFunction.Max(20 - vSrc(t, UBound(vSrc, 1)), 0)
Cells(20, 9 + t).Value = vpf(t)
Next t
MsgBox "Upper Bound Length is: " & vpf(1)


J = UBound(vSrc, 1)
'y = 1 + 2

Do
    For K = 1 To UBound(vSrc, 1)
   ' For y = 1 To UBnound(vSrc, 1)
        vRes(I, K) = vSrc(K, J)
        'vpf(I, y) = vSrc(y, J)
        'Next y
    Next K
    J = J - 1
    I = I + 3

Loop Until I > UBound(vRes, 1)

With wsSrc


     Set rRes = .Cells(lastRow + 2, 9).Resize(UBound(vRes, 1), UBound(vRes, 2) + 
    With rRes
        .Clear
        .Value = vRes
        .EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With
End With
'MsgBox "Upper Bound Length is: " & rRes



End Sub
```

vSrc, vpf are arrays, and vpf is working gd but the ouput from cells(20,9+t)

is disappearing . i hope now it is better this is the code after what i did

if i want to place the array directly to the cells that i need how to do that?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by disappearing? Also i think this should be `vSrc(t, UBound(vSrc, 2))`

Comment: so cells(20,9+t) should output the values of vpf, but they are not, when i get my mesg, i can see the values there, then when i click okay, they are gone. . i will try vSrc(t, UBound(vSrc, 2)) .

Comment: Disappearing? Maybe it's on a the `ActiveSheet` instead of where you would expect them to be? Notice you haven't been explicit about that. I also don't quite understand why you load an array and in the same iteration you paste them to the worksheet. Might as well paste the whole array afterwards to prevent recursive calls to the worksheet object (slowing down your code)

Comment: no no they are where i need them to be let add pics so that u can see

Comment: as u can see from the image after i click okay, the output goes away.

Comment: It is a 100% match to my best knowledge. Your message box custom text says upper bound, but that's not what you are returning. You are returning the value on index 1 from `vpf` instead. Btw, my previous comment still stands. You can rework that code better.

Comment: forget about the upper bound , i was lazy to remove it, i know that is not my upper bound, "0" is what i am looking for, but after the mesgbox goes , 0,0,5.4 and 12.2 disappear also

Comment: There is not enough code to let us know what happens after the msgbox. It's a guessing game and you just need to step through your code to see what happens using `F8`

Comment: i did not know how to pass the array to the cells i need. i see what u mean, but i do not know how to do that.

Comment: i have added the rest of the code

Comment: Using `o` as a variable name is a bad idea. It is too easily confused with `0`. That might even be what you did with `vSrc(t, UBound(vSrc, 1)), 0)` (Either that, or you defined a variable but never used it, also a bad idea). In any event, please post a [mcve]. The code that you posted uses all sorts of things (such as `vSrc`) that are defined elsewhere, so we are reduced to guessing about what they are.

Comment: John Coleman, you are right i am sorry for that, vSrc is an array with the that has all the data in , and it is in another worksheet.